# How to have “File, Edit, View, …” on the top of the window

Tags: 20.04, menu

I have **Ubuntu 20.04** and i was thinking can i have the "File,edit,..." menu on the top of window ?(like *Mac OS* )
[image]

and have something like this :
[image]

1-Is there any way to do that ? 
2-Is it going to be done with Tweak-tool or Dconf-editor ?

Comment: Now that I have submitted an answer, I figure maybe you want to move that menu _into the Top Panel_ like it was in Unity? (Like on e.g. 16.04?) If anything offers that on Gnome desktop, I believe it would be a "gnome shell extension"; but I don't know whether one exists for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in Firefox and Thunderbird, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> reveals it.

You can force their appearance,

- in **Firefox**: `press Alt; View > Toolbars > Menu bar`
- in **Thunderbird**: `Hamburger menu button > Customize > Menu bar`

Libreoffice, Gimp, and Inkscape have them always on. (Basically those apps that have a lot of features in these menus.)

Some other apps don't seem to have it any more. (E.g. Nautilus, Gedit, Evince, Rhythmbox; those ones that had limited complexity in these menus in the first place.)

It seems in the new Gnome UI a lot of such menus had been migrated into the so-called "hamburger menu button"s, located usually around the top right side of windows. (Plus into a few other, always-present buttons nearby.)

I believe this was in the name of better compatibility with touchscreens and hybrid input computers where a laptop's screen is detachable from the body and can function as a tablet.

---

Your second screenshot seems to originate from the Unity desktop, which was default desktop for several earlier Ubuntu releases, but whose development — as far as I know — was unfortunately discontinued. In recent releases (like your 20.04) you get the Gnome desktop by default, where the things I above described apply.

If you want to explore alternative desktops, get yourself a USB drive, download iso images for Ubuntu MATE, Lubuntu, and Kubuntu, put them on the USB one at a time, and launch them in "Try out without installing" mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ....yeah the second one is from the unity desktop because i didn't find a photo related to Gnome desktop