# Move the "File View" bar to the very top bar

Tags: gnome, customization, gnome-shell-extension

This question is, very probably, duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320326/how-to-have-file-edit-view-on-the-top-of-the-window), but this duplicate does not answer my question.
I want to move the "File View" bar to the top bar like in Unity or macOS

Since I cannot post images due to I am newbie on this site, I can just provide links to screenshots

[Current top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7lp9.png) [macOS top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQHT1.png)

Does Gnome have any extension that does **exactly** what I want?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Implementing a global menu is not easy in linux, because of the different graphical toolkits in use. The Ubuntu Unity desktop managed to to it to quite some extent for GTK applications and, using a different mechanisms, Firefox/Thunderbird. Modern GTK applications move away from the traditional menu bar, so there efforts for a global menu do not make much sense anymore.